# remove or replace incorrect string

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql dump with incorrect URLS.

```
Text stuff goes here before the url <a href="http://www.incorrectsite.com/incorrecturl/2000/xxx/yyy/zzz.html>Correct Text</a>
```

In the correct urls

```
Another text stuff goes here. <a href="http://www.correctsite.com/correctsite/uploads/2000/xxx/yyy/zzz.html>Correct Text</a>. And here too.
```

I am required to **remove** incorrect url and clean up the SQL dump.

I can find the records using,

```
select * from tbl_incorrect WHERE like '%incorrecturl%'
```

*Each returning value for the URLs are different from each other.*

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you want to fix these URLs in the DB with a query, or in the dump file with PHP find/replace?

Comment: So you want to replace all the old_url with new_url in a plain SQL dump file? `sed` could make it.

Comment: find and replace in $sometexteditor

Comment: The idea is to find the incorrect URLs and remove them completely, and not replace.

Answer (score 0):

You can open dump into vim and replace all URLs:

```
:%s/www.incorrectsite.com\/incorrecturl/www.correctsite.com\/correctsite\/uploads/g
:wq
```

or use sed:

```
sed 's/www.incorrectsite.com\/incorrecturl/www.correctsite.com\/correctsite\/uploads/g' incorrect.sql > correct.sql
```

Comment: The idea is to find the incorrect URLs and remove them completely, and not replace.

Comment: @Kush Do you mean to remove link <a href="badurl">text</a> from dump?

Comment: Yes, but need to leave text part within <a> tags. I tried with Regex without much success.

Answer (score 0):

There is MySQL's native REPLACE() method. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

If you have to go through an entire table of records, then you could use a stored procedure with a CURSOR.

If you have a text version of the dump, you could also utilize find and replace feature, like in unix you could utilize 'sed' to regex and replace within the SQL dump file.

Comment: The idea is to find the incorrect URLs and remove them completely, and not replace.

Comment: Okay. So are you removing just the URL text or are you completely deleting the column record? If the former apply same method i described with an empty string. If the latter, use the MySQL cursor approach http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html and delete the entry.

Comment: I would need to remove only the URL text, not the complete column record. i will check the cursors doc you attached.

Comment: I highly recommend using cursors in MySQL. I use them a lot in DBA. Set yourself up with some procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Use replace

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text') where field_name like = "%unwanted text%"
```

Comment: The issue is not this simply. Need a method to identify the URL from the selected text, e.g. select text in between '<a' and '</a>' which would be random, then replace it with a empty string.